# Month field & Year Field to date?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, reporting-services

Seemed simple until I realized I didn't get it right...

I have a report with a Month name and year number as input parameters.
Based on that info I want to compare it to my date field called timestamp.

How do I get the first of the month and year I specified?

My attempts:

```
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@year),MONTH(@month),1)
```

I also tried building a `string` with `@month+' '1'+','@year` but had no luck.

Comment: do you have an integer value corresponding to each of the Month Names you have as a parameter. If not you will have to convert those before you use datefromparts(). To the best of my knowledge it only accepts integers

Answer (score 0):

You only need to use the following

```
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(@year,@month,1)
```

`MONTH()` and `YEAR()` functions are used to extract Month and Year Parts from a DATE or DATETIME value. Here you are constructing DATE from Parts hence only use MONTH and YEAR Values.

And you would write the query something like follows:

```
SELECT * FROM TableName 
WHERE [TimeStamp] > DATEFROMPARTS(@Year , @Month ,1 )
```